# why typeorm (v.0.2.40) for mysql when update data always return affected: 1 although it didnt update anything?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, mariadb, typeorm

i need to know when i update the data and there is change in database, normally affected rows will return `1`, and when there is no changes, it will return `0`

but i try with both of this:

`getManager().createQueryBuilder(Area).update(data).where({ area_id: id }).execute();`

`getRepository().update(id, data);`

but, always return this `UpdateResult { generatedMaps: [], raw: [], affected: 1 }`

if using raw query:

`getManager().connection.query('update area set .... where ....')`

it will return this:

```
ResultSetHeader {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  info: 'Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0',
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningStatus: 0,
  changedRows: 0
}
```

with this i can get the changedRows value to use in next action, but need to generate manual query

driver: `mysql`, `mariadb`

using mysql2 node modules

thank you

Comment: Im having an similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068602/typeorm-update-method-doesnt-work-when-using-repository , need help